# Using autowired beans in an object created at runtime

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a class B which implements W interface. It has a default implementation of W's method. class C and D override  default implementation for which they need a service whose bean is instantiated by spring. String a and b comes from user and hence there is no way I can create a bean of B/C/D in advance. So I have a factory which creates a new object based on user parameters (it will create B/C/D based on parameters). Is there any clean way I can use service beans(aa/bb/cc/dd etc.) from inside C and D (spring autowires during server startup, at that time parameter required for instantiating B/C/D are not available) or is there any better way to solve the problem ?

```
 Class B implements W{
      String a;
      String b;
      B (String a, String b);

      w_method(){

      }
   }

    Class C extends B {
      @Autowired
      Service aa;

      @Autowired
      Service bb;

      @Autowired
      Service cc;

      @override
      w_method(){
      }
    }

Class D extends B {
  @Autowired
  Service dd;

  @override
  w_method(){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the simplest method would be to wire the services into the factory and call setters on the B / C / D objects before you return them, rather than attempting to use `@Autowired`.

Or use axtavt's constructor argument method. If you want to avoid depending on `ApplicationContext`, you can use [Lookup Method Injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection), but you'll have to patch Spring per this blog post: http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/creating-prototype-spring-beans-on.html

Comment: First solution worked well + using reflection for setters made the code very flexible yet simple.

Answer (score 8):

There are three possible approaches:

- The fact that constructor arguments come from user doesn't mean that these objects cannot be created by Spring.

  You can declare them as Spring beans of scope `prototype` and do the following in your factory:

  ```
  public C createC(String a, String b) {
      return applicationContext.getBean("c", a, b);
  }
  ```

  A disadvantage of this method is that your factory depends on `ApplicationContext`.
- You can annotate these classes with `@Configurable` and enable AspectJ weaving. In this case Spring will configure objects of these classes even if you create them with `new`. See [7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable).
- You can trigger autowiring manually as

  ```
  applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(...);
  ```

  This approach is useful when you don't have control over creation of objects that you need to autowire (servlets, etc).

Comment: Will try configuring using @Configurable and AspectJ tomorrow. Thanks for help :)